# How can I call jquery function from javascript code?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, client-side

I'm using RadAjaxPanel by telerik and it has ClientEvents-OnResponseEnd client-side event. So I've written JavaScript function:

```
function OnResponseEnd(ajaxPanel, eventArgs) {
        // call jQuery here
    };
```

and my question is how to call jQuery function inside? I'd like to manipulate some html elements with .slide(..) function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

jQuery *is* javascript - it's a js library. Just call the function, e.g. $(this).slide(); in the function.

Answer (score 4):

You can call the jQuery functions inside the function you showed above. Of course, you have to import the jQuery library before you can do that.

Example:

```
function OnResponseEnd(ajaxPanel, eventArgs) {
    $('div').slide(...);
};
```